# Visual Studio 2015 Project Templates with ADFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, adfs

Visual Studio 2013 project template with MVC and Web API works with ADFS on-Premises Authority. Web AIP only project template doesn't work with the ADFS authentication.

However none of Visual studio 2015 MVC or web api project templates work with the ADFS on-Premises Authority. especially Web API asp.net 5 template doesn't have an option of ADFS on-Premises Authority.

Anyone makes Visual Studio 2015 web api project work with ADFS on-Premises Authority?

Answer (score 1):

New ASP.NET project.

Use 4.5.3 Templates **NOT** ASP.NET 5.

Choose MVC / Web API as required.

Change Authentication.

Work and School Accounts.

Change "Cloud - Single Organisation" to "On-Premises" in dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested a new 4.5.2(not 3) template project MVC/Web api but still doesn't work. On-Premises Authority--->https://adfs.*.*/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml  AppID URI: https://webapi.*.*. It worked with VS2013 template. I found that web api entries are far different between the 2015 project and 2013 project.

Comment: What if I have already created the project and would now like to integrate ADFS auth? How can I do this?